# HTML container with up/down scrolling content showing at least N items

Tags: html, scroll

I have a dashboard with several widgets and one is causing me troubles. It is a widget (DIV HTML element with row-by-row content) which currently has a fixed height, which is able to scroll vertically because it MAY contain a lot of content.

The scrolling ability is implemented via ngIscroll from [iScroll-v5.1.3](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5).

I cannot show a precise content, but this should point out the problem:

[image]

The green area is problematic. It lists the phone calls made during the last x days, while the red area below lists the calendar entries for the next 30 days, including today. The image is exaggerated in that it's width is normally bigger than its height! So a day which has about 7 phone calls won't be able to show them all, thus the need for using iScroll, to scroll through the phone calls, but a day having only 2 calls would leave unused space below the second call and above the calendar. The (red) calendar entries also have an instance of iScroll, because they'll never fit into an entire screen.

What I want to archive is that the green area shrinks to the "at lease 4(=x) phone calls". Show me at least 4 phone calls, else I need to scroll. If only two phone calls occurred during that day, I want the bit of free space below to be removed and the calendar to be starting to use up its space.

Comment: Why not use `max-height` and `height: auto`?

Comment: Thanks, will test it tomorrow. I believe that the reason for choosing iScroll was its ability to seamlessly support touch interfaces (the dashboard is also running on tablets), which normal div|contenteditable doesn't (or alt least didn't) support.